# How do you delete an argument from a namespace

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

**Question**: Given an argparse parser instance with some arguments added, is there a way to delete/remove an argument defined for it?

**Why**: Considering the exemple below:

```
>>>import argparse
>>>parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>>parser.add_argument('--imagePath', action = "store", default = 'toto')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--imagePath'], dest='imagePath', nargs=None, const=None, default='toto', type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>>args = parser.parse_args()
>>>args
Namespace(imagePath='toto')
>>>parser.add_argument('--resultPath', action = "store", default = 'titi')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--resultPath'], dest='resultPath', nargs=None, const=None, default='titi', type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>>args = parser.parse_args()
>>>args
Namespace(imagePath='toto', resultPath='titi')
```

If we will, later in the script, change the value of the args.imagePath?

I does not found a method for change the value, but if I can delete / remove the argument imagePath it could be possible to define again imagePath with a new value !

Comment: Why would you `parse_args` and then change the argument definitions?

Comment: Why parse then ignore the input parameters? Do you actually *want* to remove the parameter, or just replace its value (and if the former, why not just ignore it)?

Comment: In a big script, there is a lot of possible arguments with some that are connected. I just add a new argument, but depending of the value of it, i need to change dynamically, in flight, the value for others. hpaulj gave the correct way to do it properly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just do:

```
args.imagePath = 'newvalue'
```

`args` is an `argparse.Namespace` object.  This is a simple class, that just adds a display method - what you see with `print(args)`.  Otherwise, all the normal Python object methods work.  So you can fetch, set, even add attributes as desired.

The `parser` tries to keep its assumptions about the namespace object to a minimum.  It uses the most generic access methods - `hasattr`, `getattr`, `setattr`.

e.g.

```
dest = 'imagePath'
value = 'newvalue'
setattr(args, dest, value)
```

You can also delete, e.g.

```
del args.imagePath
delattr(args, 'imagePath')
```

I'm tempted to change your title to 'How do you delete an argument from a namespace'.  I don't think you mean to delete the argument (Action created by `add_argument`) from the `parser` itself.  Your focus is on the namespace created by parsing.

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much hpaulj, you have exactly understood what was my problem and what I needed to fix it ! Very clear answer ! Indeed the good title would be "How do you delete an argument from a namespace". Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

To delete an argparse argument, one can use the oneliner

```py
imagePath = args.__dict__.pop('imagePath')
```

Here the deleted value is even stored at the same time in a new variable.

If the deleted value is not needed at all, then just:

```py
del args.imagePath
```